# Function takes a reference parameter with a default value

Tags: c++

Based on 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/

```
explicit vector ( const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

This vector constructor takes a reference parameter which has default value of Allocator(). What I learn from this function signature is that a function can take a reference parameter with default value.

This the demo code I play with VS2010.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void funA(const int& iValue=5) // reference to a template const int 5 why?
{
    cout << iValue << endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    funA();
    funA(10);
    return 0;
}
```

are there some rules to guide this syntax usage (i.e. a reference parameter with a default value)?

Comment: What is it that you are confused about, that you think rules might clear up?  The syntax seems very clear to me, hence, I don't know how to help you.

Comment: why it is meaningful to allow a reference to local temporary variable? I assume that reference should always point to some real variables. - thank you

Comment: How is that any less "real" then a variable that exists within a function alone? It simply isn't named and goes out of scope as soon as the function returns

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Const references may be bound to temporary objects, in which case the lifetime of the temporary extends to the lifetime of the reference.

Comment: Help a noob out; does this mean references must be lvalues but const references can be both rvalues and lvalues?

Comment: @dreamlax: Indeed it does. Modifying an rvalue is undefined behaviour in C++03, I believe, that's why the reference must be const.

Comment: @dreamlax: not exactly. lvalue and rvalue refer to syntactical *expressions* (in C++98 an expression must be either lvalue or rvalue). The distinction originated with C, where the point of rvalues (C non-lvalues) was that they might conceivably end up just as part of the machine code instructions, not stored in any memory location. In short an expression that produces a value is an rvalue expression, while an an expression that refers to some object in memory (which an expression of reference type necessarily does) is an lvalue expression. Hoping I've not over-simplified,

Comment: @DeadMG: not exactly that either. Consider `std::string( "uh" )[0] = 'o'`. This is a perfectly well-defined modification of an rvalue, enabled by C++98's support for calling member functions on rvalue expressions of class type. Ironically, due to auto-generated assignment op member func you can do like `f() = structValue` but not `f().intMember = 42`. The whole concept is just a bit flawed... ;-)

Comment: Well, now I feel like the President's advisor in "Independence Day" movie  --  "not exactly..." :-) Can't edit earlier comment, so, I meant *data* memory location. Machine code is of course also in memory.

Comment: @Mr Nimzicki (presidential advisor / @Alf): The expression `10` (by itself) is an rvalue expression though, isn't it? Yet it can be provided to a function expecting reference type (as in the example in the OQ).

Comment: @dreamlax: yes, it's like @DeadMG wrote, a temporary is created, for the lifetime of the reference. Only exception is where you return a reference from a function. Then the temporary is created but ceases to exist as the function returns, so in that case, UB. Cheers,

Comment: @Alf if we are that deep into pedantry, I should remind you of lvalues that refer to register storage. Though this does only affect C. C++ doesn't really have a forced distinction between register and memory storage =) +1 for your above explanation tho. Liking it!

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is defined in [§ 8.3.6](http://www.lcdf.org/c++/clause8.html#s8.3.6) 5 of c++03:

> A default argument expression is implicitly converted ([clause 4](http://www.lcdf.org/c++/clause4.html)) to the parameter type. The default argument expression has the same semantic constraints as the initializer expression in a declaration of a variable of the parameter type, using the copy-initialization semantics ([8.5](http://www.lcdf.org/c++/clause8.html#s8.5)).

That is, `const Type& var = val` is a valid parameter declaration only if it's also a valid variable declaration. According to [§ 8.5.3](http://www.lcdf.org/c++/clause8.html#s8.5.3) 5, it is. For `const Allocator& = Allocator()`, the following applies:

> - Otherwise, the reference shall be to a non-volatile const type (i.e., *cv1* shall be const). [...]
>
>   - If the initializer expression is an rvalue, with **T2** a class type, and "*cv1* **T1**" is reference-compatible with "*cv2* **T2**," the reference is bound in one of the following ways (the choice is implementation defined):
>
>     - The reference is bound to the object represented by the rvalue (see [3.10](http://www.lcdf.org/c++/clause3.html#s3.10)) or to a sub-object within that object.
>     - A temporary of type "*cv2* **T2**" [sic] is created, and a constructor is called to copy the entire rvalue object into the temporary. The reference is bound to the temporary or to a sub-object within the temporary.
>
>     The constructor that would be used to make the copy shall be callable whether or not the copy is actually done. [...]
>   - Otherwise, [...]

For `const int& iValue=5`, the next case applies:

> - Otherwise, the reference shall be to a non-volatile const type (i.e., *cv1* shall be const). [...]
>
>   - If the initializer expression is an rvalue[...]
>   - Otherwise, a temporary of type "*cv1* **T1**" is created and initialized from the initializer expression using the rules for a non-reference copy initialization ([8.5](http://www.lcdf.org/c++/clause8.html#s8.5)). The reference is then bound to the temporary. If **T1** is reference-related to **T2**, *cv1* must be the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv2*; otherwise, the program is ill-formed. [Example:
>
>     ```
>               const double& rcd2 = 2;         // rcd2  refers to temporary with value 2.0
>               const volatile int cvi = 1;
>               const int& r = cvi;             //  error: type qualifiers dropped
>     ```
>
>     ---end example]

In short, a real, though perhaps temporary, variable is created so the reference can refer to it. It's allowed in parameter declarations exactly so that reference parameters can take default values. Otherwise, it would be a needless restriction. The more [orthogonal](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/orthogonal.html) a language is, the easier it is to keep in your head, as you don't need to remember as many exceptions to the rules (though, arguably, allowing const references but not non-const references to be bound to rvalues is less orthogonal than disallowing any reference to be bound to an rvalue).

Comment: There are a number of other parts of the standard (e.g. § 4, 12.2) that define other behavioral aspects of default values for reference parameters, but I don't believe they impact syntax, which is what this question concerns. I've left them out to avoid going off on tangents. Does anyone know if I've missed something related to syntax in these other sections?

Answer (score 2):

The only rules I can think of are (a) that the reference must be const, because you can't bind a non-const reference to a temporary, and (b) that it's generally better *not* to use const references to pass built-in types. In other words:

(a)

```
void f(T& t = T(23)) {} // bad

void g(const T& t = T(23)) {} // fine
```

(b)

```
void f(const int& i = 23) {} // sort of ok

void g(int i = 23) {} // better
```